# what are the sequences of project_id and segment1 in pa_projects_all table in oracle r12

Tags: oracle-ebs, oaf

I am trying to find out what are the sequences belong to above mentioned entities. I would be grateful if someone find me because i tried finding them in dependencies, inside the triggers and in API without luck

Answer (score 0):

Search in Oracle docs. They give specification of each table in detail